# need a detailed guide to start scripts and applications in xfce4

Tags: shell-script, boot, startup

I am looking for a detailed explanation about where is the right place to start scripts applications during the boot process. It seems there is either confusion or not need for the detail I am looking for.

I need to know where to start application scripts as a user (my user, not root), after the pc and xfce session have been boot up , but before I as a user have logged in.

It seems that *application autostart* in xfce4 is not run as I expected above and it is only run after I have logged in.

I am using Ubuntu Studio64 14.04 64bit.

Comment: i want to start a few audio applications and of course jack. The problem is that connecting to the hardware is not possible due to several conflicts with lightdm, pulseaudio and others. so what works when I am logged in, does not work when I run it from rc.local.. and that is the hell situation i am in :)

Comment: Xfce session starts only after you log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `cron`. On Debian-based systems (and probably others, but I'm not sure which) you can use the `@reboot` directive to run a command each time the system reboots. Run `crontab -e` and add this line:

```
@reboot /path/to/your/script.sh
```

That, however, will not guarantee that the script will run *after* xfce4 since it will be executed when the `cron` daemon starts. A simple solution to that would be to make your script wait instead. Just add a line like this:

```
 until pidof xfce4; do sleep 1; done
```

That will cause your script to wait until `xfce4` is started at which point it will continue and run as expected. If you need to run programs you don't want to edit, you can add that to the crontab itself:

```
 @reboot until pidof xfce4; do sleep 1; done && /path/to/your/script.sh
```